# Accessing system after GNOME failed

Tags: rhel, gnome, scientific-linux

I have difficulties to access GNOME in Scientific Linux 6.5

I did try to set automatic login following [wiki.archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM). In `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` I added:

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLogin=username
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
```

After re-boot I have main welcome screen of Scientific linux, after comes blank screen with a "working" round mouse pointer and it does not proceed to GNOME session.

I can't figure out how to access `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to change added lines and comeback to a previous configuration.

Is there any way to go arround and start the GNOME, or to access terminal, or to run linux in command line mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's hanging just because of a problem with a setting made within GNOME you might try logging in on one of the tty's (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) as root, `mv`'ing the user's home directory to something else (e.g "username.old") then re-creating it, giving that user ownership on that home directory. When that user logs into GNOME again, it should re-create his profile with all default settings and the files can be moved over from the renamed directory.